# Images don't appear at categories pages

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, image

I have some products, which his images don't appear in his category page but if you look the product page, you can see them. Any idea?

For example in this page `http://s513806032.mialojamiento.es/en/children?p=2` you can't see the image of  child star shooter but if you go to his product 
page you can see some images.

Answer (score 1):

If  want to show a image to product listing then you need to set this `image as small_image of  that product.`

As per as my concept,you have not set `small_image, image, thumbnails image` value for  `those products`

[image]

Comment: No, it is already selected for one image

Comment: flush catalog image cache from admin>System> cache management

Comment: Well it' doesn't work :(